# Java Properties Wrapper

Tags: java

I've decided to make a wrapper class for the `java.util.Properties` class since, in its current state, it only allows for storing and reading `String` values.

Is there any way I can improve the following code?

```
public final class Prefs {

    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();
    private static OutputStream out;
    public static final File test = new File("settings.properties");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            set("hello", "5");

            int hello = get("hello", 1337);
            System.out.println(hello == 5);

            set("hello", "34");
            hello = get("hello", 1337);
            System.out.println(hello == 34);

            remove("hello");
            hello = get("hello", 1337);
            System.out.println(hello == 1337);
        } finally {
            save();
        }
    }

    static {
        try {
            if (!test.exists()) {
                test.createNewFile();
            }
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(test));
            out = new FileOutputStream(test);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> T get(String key, T defaultValue) {
        if (!properties.containsKey(key)) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);
        if (defaultValue instanceof Long) {
            return (T) new Long(value);
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) new Integer(value);
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Short) {
            return (T) new Short(value);
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Byte) {
            return (T) new Byte(value);
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Double) {
            return (T) new Double(value);
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Float) {
            return (T) new Float(value);
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
            return (T) new Boolean(value);
        }
        return (T) value;
    }

    public static void set(String key, String value) {
        properties.setProperty(key, "" + value);
    }

    public static void remove(String key) {
        properties.remove(key);
    }

    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void save() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            properties.store(out, "");
            out.flush();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is the `try-finally` code block really required in your `main()` method?
2. Your `get()` ***fails*** if the default value is not any of those primitive wrapper classes. What if I want a `BigDecimal` instance? `"1.0"` can't be casted to that.
3. On a related note, you are relying on auto-boxing, which may lead to unexpected consequences:

   ```
   // code compiles, but throws NullPointerException here
   int npe = getValue("invalid-key", (Integer) null);
   ```
4. Maybe this is just a quick prototyping, but if you do decide to make this a full-fledged library class, you should not be having the `main()` method, the `static` initialization block, or your `static` fields. The fields should become class fields where `Prefs` needs to be instantiated. Testing should go into its own class.
5. On another related note, you don't necessarily need to create temporary files for testing. There is a [`Properties.load(Reader)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) method that will work with a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html), which can be used in turn to wrap your test `String`s/lines.
6. I don't think there's a benefit to instantiating a `FileOutputStream` object immediately after you have `load()`-ed the file. Things may happen between the loading and storing of properties, so regardless of whether you have this object or not, the storing process may still fail afterwards. Also, it seems like you do not need to explicitly `flush()` after calling `store()` as that is already done according to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-):

   > After the entries have been written, the output stream is flushed. The output stream remains open after this method returns.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer primitive getters:

`````
    public long get(String key, long defaultValue) {
        if (!p.containsKey(key)) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        String val = p.getProperty(key);
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(val);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read property " + key + ". Value is not a long.", e);
        }
    }

````
`````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please include a proper explanation for your preference, so others can learn from it. Also please note that the question is from 2015.